# UWP app - TrySetWallpaperImageAsync Failed on desktop pc

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop

I'm been working on an app to set the Microsoft Bing Image as wallpaper, but for some reason the code works on mobile but doesn't seems to works on desktop.

Here's the main code that setup the wallpaper:

> **Note:** ***imageViewModel.Bitmap*** is a type of ***WriteableBitmap***

```
const string fileName = "start_temp.jpg";

        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
            Stream pixelStream = imageViewModel.Bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
            byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
            await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)imageViewModel.Bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)imageViewModel.Bitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }

        if (await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(file))
        {
            showToastNotification("Start background image set successfull!");
        }
```

The codes work perfectly on mobile, but not the same on desktop. I have use ***UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported()*** and confirm the device is supported.

### There is a scenario that works:

1. First save the ***WriteableBitmap*** as jpg image in a place like desktop.
2. Copy the jpg image to ***ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder***.
3. Finally use ***TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(...)*** to setup wallpaper.

I have no idea why the code above doesn't works on desktop =(

> Here's the code that how I download the image:

```
private async Task<WriteableBitmap> loadImage(string url)
    {
        var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);
        byte[] imageByte = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1920, 1080);

        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomStream))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes(imageByte);

                await writer.StoreAsync();

                await writer.FlushAsync();

                writer.DetachStream();
            }

            randomStream.Seek(0);

            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(randomStream);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: I tested with your code on my desktop computer, it works well. My OS Build is 10586.494, Version 1511. Do you get any exception when you use these code? Or just  the `TrySetWallpaperImageAsync` method returns `false`? Have you tested in any other machine? If you still has this issue, please share a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have the same OS Build as yours. 
I didn't get any exception for it, but the `TrySetWallpaperImageAsync` method always return `false`.
I just added the code to the question that how I download the image, hope it might help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After tested my app on two difference devices and works fine as well, it seems like my PC was having problem with `TrySetWallpaperImageAsync` or `TrySetLockscreenImageAsync` API.

After some research the problem was the developer environment issue, which the Visual Studio / Windows SDK on my PC is having some issue to run the code.

I deploy a package and install it on my PC, everything is fine.